# Couldn't run Google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I can't run my Google map V2 in my activity, the map is launch by an intent with
`Graves_menu` how start the activity `Graves_geolocalisation`.

I have 1 package named `graves_de_mer` where I have 2 activity :
- Graves_menu
- Graves_geolocalisation

I have my API key, my google-play-services_lib...

My errors :

```
E/dalvikvm(336): Could not find class 'graves_de_mer.Graves_geolocalisation', referenced from method graves_de_mer.Graves_menu$1.onItemClick 
E/AndroidRuntime(336): FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
E/AndroidRuntime(336): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: graves_de_mer.Graves_geolocalisation
```

Apparently the error don't come from my project, I have run an another project find on internet how works and I have the same problem : `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

Please help I don't understand why it doesn't work :(

Comment: Have you declared `Graves_geolocalisation` in manifest?

Comment: Thank you to answer, yes i have declare Graves_geolocalisation in my manifest. But it's very strange that an another project find on internet how work, can't be run on my Laptop :(

Comment: Are you using Eclipse ADT 22 ?

Comment: Yes, I have find my error : I have to use Android Support Library, And it work on a real device :)